# How to render chinese characters and other languages like arabic with cairo in python?

Tags: character, render, arabic, cairo, cjk

it seems that cairo can't correctly render text like characters in chinese and arabic. Could anyone tell me how to render these texts in cairo? Can pango with cairo in python render these characters? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you select an appropriate `font face`, you should be able to draw the texts straightforwardly.

```
cr.select_font_face('Noto Sans CJK SC')
cr.move_to(100, 100)
cr.set_source_rgb(0, 0, 0)

cr.show_text('好吧')
```

To list available fonts, type in console:

```
$ fc-list : family
```

Comment: So sorry for  the late reply! It works! Thanks ardget! This is more convenient to render texts with alternative alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

According to [cairo's FAQ](https://cairographics.org/FAQ/#using_pango), the answer is "use PangoCairo":

> [...] you learn that cairo_show_text is part of cairo's "toy" text API. It's fine for quick demos, and for learning how to use cairo, but it's not intended for use in actual applications.
>
> It's not hard to run into some of the limitations of cairo_show_text.
>
> [...]
>
> Fortunately, the pango library exists and does do sophisticated text layout, shaping, etc. and integrates very nicely with cairo. We heartily recommend that "real" applications wanting to display text with cairo use pango to do it.